# gradle maven dependencies proguard trouble

Tags: android, maven, gradle, proguard

In my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(":Vendor:NineOldAndroids:Library")
    compile project(":Vendor:Unionpay:upomp_Res_v1_1")
    compile project(":Vendor:ViewPagerIndicator:Library")
    compile project(":Vendor:SlidingMenu-library")
}
```

I have a dependency support-v4, it's a maven-repo(Why don't I include support-v4.jar directly? I think maven-repo a better way manage dependencies, it's easy to avoid to include support-v4 many times)

But a trouble comes up, I need proguard my project, maven-repo makes me can't set `-libraryjars 'libs/android-support-v4.jar'`  because the support-v4 is in somewhere "dynamically"

I can't find an official way to to this, anyone can solve it ?

Comment: @flx  they are totally different, My problem is how to prevent support-v4(from maven-repo) from proguard, and I think I have found the answer!  `Copying resources from program jar [/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/18.0.0/support-v4-18.0.0.jar] (filtered)`
this is proguard log, proguard automatically do it for us!

Comment: Hi, did you modify your proguard-project.txt at all?